# •Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

After writing author name and text and clicking on add comment, on web i get the error:

> •Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.

I dont understand, I followed everything in the tutorial..

**in models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**in forms.py:**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('author','text',)

    widgets = {
        'author': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'textinputclass'}),
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'editable medium-editor-textarea'}),
    }
```

**in views.py:**

```
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
   else:
       form = CommentForm()
   return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, it's critical to understanding Python code.

Comment: i dont know where my code indentation is wrong,, i checked everywhere

Comment: You need indentation after `class Comment`. You need indentation after `def add_comment_to_post`

Comment: Please take the plain text headings like `in views.py` out of the code blocks. I fixed that for you before, but you undid it.

Comment: thats how i wrote the code..can u please check now?thank you!

Comment: Please post the code the way it really is. Paste the correctly indented code, then use control-K or the `{}` tool to mark it as code.

Comment: this is how i wrote it

Comment: Then you wrote it wrong. The body of the `Comment` class has to be indented.

Comment: fixed the model.py.. now...sorry...still doesnt work

Comment: _Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices._ Is that the entire error message? In any case, I strongly recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general, before anything else. Finding a solution to this specific issue won't be of much value to you.

Comment: yes it is! it shows that error when i try to add the comment after writing it!